# Trying to update mysql table with ColdFusion MX 7

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I have been trying to update a table in MySQL 5.0 with Coldfusion MX 7.  But the query only updates/adds the first records and does not update/add the other 60,000 records.

```
<cfquery name="count" datasource="voyager">
SELECT 
        PATRON.PATRON_ID, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_CHARGES, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_BOOKINGS, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_DISTRIBUTIONS, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_SHORT_LOANS, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_CHARGES_UB, 
        PATRON.HISTORICAL_REQUESTS_UB
FROM PATRON
</cfquery>


<cfquery name="update" datasource="patrons">
    <cfoutput>
    REPLACE INTO patrondailyusecounttotals (PATRON_ID, HISTORICAL_CHARGES)
    VALUES ('#count.PATRON_ID#', '#count.HISTORICAL_CHARGES#')
    </cfoutput>
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a loop:

```html
<cfquery name="count" datasource="voyager">
  SELECT 
    PATRON.PATRON_ID, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_CHARGES, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_BOOKINGS, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_DISTRIBUTIONS, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_SHORT_LOANS, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_CHARGES_UB, 
    PATRON.HISTORICAL_REQUESTS_UB
  FROM 
    PATRON
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="count">
  <cfquery name="update" datasource="patrons">
    REPLACE INTO patrondailyusecounttotals (PATRON_ID, HISTORICAL_CHARGES)
    VALUES (
      <cfqueryparam value="#PATRON_ID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">, 
      <cfqueryparam value="#HISTORICAL_CHARGES#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
    )
  </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Note that using `<cfqueryparam>` is the recommended approach here. It will speed up the "inner query" by a lot, since with each loop iteration after the first one only the parameter values are transmitted to the server (instead of transmitting the full SQL code every time).

---

**EDIT**

The original version of the answer recommended the following, but obviously that's is not enough in a situation involving separate database servers.

```html
<cfquery name="update" datasource="patrons">
  REPLACE INTO 
     patrondailyusecounttotals (PATRON.PATRON_ID, HISTORICAL_CHARGES)
  SELECT 
     PATRON_ID, HISTORICAL_CHARGES
  FROM 
     PATRON
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to do that will an oracle table on one machine and a mysql table on another machine.  I am using coldfusion because that is the only way I can think of to bring the data together from the two sites.

Comment: @schwartzray Ah! That's an important bit of information. :) I did not realize those were two separate data sources. Okay, you'll need a loop, then. See modified answer.

Comment: @schwartzray Don't forget to tick the "Accept" check mark when this is what you needed. Oh, and welcome to SO and everything. :)